# admin class not available after putting own class code in separate file

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I have extended the class WP_List_Table in order to create my own tables. That worked fine, but after putting my own extended classes into a separate file the base class is not available any more:

```
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) )
    {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );                      
    }

    if ( ! class_exists( 'myListClass' ) )
    {
            require_once( plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'inc/mylistclass.php' );
    }
```

and

```
class myListClass extends WP_List_Table
{
```

If I put the content from my file directly into the script, it works, but when loading the code as described, I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_List_Table' not found in....

Comment: you have require file where class exist?

Comment: I am not shure, what you mean, shall i include the base class file again into my class file? For some reason, ABSPATH is not defined there. But the main problem exists: I do not understand, why the code movement into a file makes WP_List_Table invisible.

Answer (score 0):

File name: class-my-list-table.php

```
<?php
if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php';
}

class My_List_Table extends WP_List_Table {
...
}

...
```

Use the file in another plugin file whose content may look like this:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_list_table_menu' );

function my_list_table_menu() {
    add_menu_page(
        'My List Table',
        'My List Table',
        'manage_options',
        'my-list-table',
        'my_list_table_callback'
    );
}

function my_list_table_callback() {
    ob_start();
    include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'class-my-list-table.php';
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo $template;
}
```

I've learned WP_List_Table by watching https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLT9miexWCpPWD3BOrqHmwaXL2LLVb6kpg. Thanks for the author.